# PHP Swift Mail and Outlook 365

Tags: swiftmailer, office365

I'm trying to use PHP Swiftmail (Laravel Package) but it keeps throwing this stupid exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with
>   message 'Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "+OK
>   The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
>   [QwBPADEAUABSADAANwBDAEEAMAAxADMALgBuAGEAbQBwAHIAZAAwADcALgBwAHIAbwBkAC4AbwB1AHQAbABvAG8AawAuAGMAbwBtAA==]"

Anyone come accross this and know how to fix it?

regards

Comment: Can you provide your code to show what you are designating as your mail server.  In my experience you cannot send mail through Office 365 using PHP, you need a separate mail server.

Comment: Here are some example settings we've tried and got the same exact message as the OP. 

smtpUsername = email@example.com 
smtpPassword = "MYPASSWORD" 
smtpHost = smtp.office365.com 
smtpPort = 995 
from = email@example.com 
fromName = "MY NAME"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be connecting on the wrong port. I am able to send via Office 365 using:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.office365.com', 587, 'tls')
              ->setUsername($emailUsername)
              ->setPassword($emailPass)
              ;
```

Obviously you would need to use the appropriate variables for username and password.

I do encounter regular 'submission rate exceeded' errors though even while using the throttler plugin set at 6.